# GoogleMap wrapped in GestureDetector does not receive drag event

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

How can I make `GoogleMap` to receive pointer events when it is wrapped by a `GestureDetector`, the following code prevents the map to be dragged:

```
GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
    onVerticalDragStart: _onMapDragged,
    onHorizontalDragStart: _onMapDragged,
    child: GoogleMap(...
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: The GoogleMap onCameraMove, onCameraIdle callbacks might be of interest, as well as https://stackoverflow.com/q/57061134/805003 .

Comment: have you ever resolve this problem..??

Answer (score 0):

I think it may depend on what you need to do with that Gesture Detector..
I was having a similar problem using a GestureDetector to open/close a menu drawer.
So my solution was to create a `control` variable to check if the Menu was opened or closed and then set `null` the event callbacks of the GestureDetector widget, something like this:

```
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onVerticalDragStart: isDraggable ? _doVerticalDrag : null,
  onHorizontalDragStart: isDraggable ? _doHorizontalDrag : null,
  child: GoogleMap(),
);
```

So when `isDraggable` is `false` the map will receive the drag actions.

Hope this helps to someone else having a similar problem.